# how to merge adjacent NumPy rows that have similar last column value into new row?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

``how do u go about solving this problem?
i have 30 rows array that have columns (seq, high, low, statues) the goal is to merge similar rows but only when they are adjacent to each other in the seq.
the new row will have the max of the high reading, and the mini of the low reading, and statues will be the same of the similar row.

for example, if row 0 statues == "balanced" and row 1 statues == "not balanced" ,

Blockquote

we don't merge it, we just move it to the new list.
but if row 0 and row 1, and 2 have the same statues of balanced, then append new column into the new list with seq 1, high = max of the 2 high value, low = mini of the 2 low value, and statues
i tried using an if-statement, but it is very long statement if i have 20 convictive "balances" in a arow

---

seq,high,low,statuse

0,55,53,balanced

1,53.75,51,not bal

2,52.5,51.25,balanced

3,53,50.5,balanced

4,51.5,49.75,balanced
5,51,49.25,not bal
6,50.25,49.25,not bal
7,49.25,48.75,not bal
8,48.75,47.25,balanced
9,47.5,45.25,balanced
10,47,46,not bal
11,46.75,44,balanced
12,45.25,43.75,not bal
13,44.25,42.25,not bal
14,42.75,41.5,balanced
15,44.25,42.5,balanced
16,44.25,42.25,not bal
17,46,43.5,balanced
18,46.75,45.25,not bal
19,46.25,45,balanced
20,46.5,44.25,balanced
21,44,43,balanced
22,43.5,42.25,not bal
23,44.25,42.5,not bal
24,43.75,41.5,balanced
25,41.5,39.5,not bal
26,42.5,40.25,not bal
27,42.75,40.75,not bal
28,43.75,41.75,balanced
29,42,39.5,balanced
30,40.5,39.25,balanced

and this is the desired output
seq,high,low,statuse
0,55,53,balanced
1,53.75,51,not bal
3,53,49.75,balanced
4,51,48.75,not bal
5,48.75,45.25,balanced
6,47,46,not bal
7,46.75,44,balanced
8,45.25,42.25,not bal
9,44.25,51.5,balanced
10,44.25,42.25,not bal
11,46,43.5,balanced
12,46.75,45.25,not bal
13,46.5,43,balanced
14,44.25,42.25,not bal
15,43.75,41.5,balanced
16,42.75,39.5,not bal
17,43.75,39.25,balanced

[original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SEWl.png)
[what i am hopping to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61lip.png)

Comment: You write _if row 0 and row 1, and 2 have the same statues …, then append new column … max of the 2 high value, … mini of the 2 low value_ - but rows 0, 1 and 2 give not 2, but 3 high and low values. You should correct this inconsistency (to as it was before version 4).

Comment: Why is in _what i am hopping to get_ seq 2 missing?

Answer (score 0):

> how do u go about solving this problem?

One way is to make a DataFrame (say `df`) from the array and use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to merge the rows with same status.

```
from itertools import groupby
d = [(lambda dfr: (max(dfr['high']), min(dfr['low']), s))(pandas.DataFrame(list(r)))
     for s, r in groupby(df.itertuples(False), lambda a: a.statuse)]
# if you want a NumPy array:
a = np.array(d, dtype=[('high','f'),('low','f'),('statuse','O')])
```

Comment: thank you so much , i actually gave up on this question , thank you . i did not even check if it actually work or not yet , but i thought i thank you first .

Comment: worked exactly like i needed to do . thank you much .